# Can i use a NavigationView for each swiftui view or i must use only one for the whole app?

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

Should i use only one single NavigationView for all views or should i define a new NavigationView for each view and how can i implement a perfect navigation structure?

i'm still new in using this concept and need more details on how to handle navigations in Swiftui app, thanks for help

Comment: One NavigationView per view hierarchy (ie, per-window) is preferable. It is possible to place NavigationView into each other, but it looks weird and behaviour might be in some use-cases unpredictable.

Comment: thanks dear, i need to understand how it work it's really new concept that never before i used or met

Comment: actually i used only one at the root view but all navigationlinks are working w without puting them inside a navigationview i really don't know why